# how to post with ajax to secured controller in Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I am trying to send an Json datatype to a secured controller `(is_granted(ROLE_ADMIN))`, but, as you can guess, i can't get it to work, i get a `405 method not allowed` response.

When i send it to an unsecured controller it works, so i have to let the controller know the post gets send with an admin role, but how?

This is my controller:

```
/**
* @Route("/admin")
* @Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')")
*/
class AdminController extends Controller {

    /**
    * Lists all Project entities.
    *
    * @Route("/savesortorder", name="save_sort_order")
    * @Security()
    */
    public function orderAction(Request $request) {
      $response = json_encode(array('message' => 'Saved succesfully!'));
      return new Response($response, 200);
    }
```

and this is my ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/TMC/web/app_dev.php/admin/project/savesortorder",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: object,
    cache: false,
    success: function () {
```

Comment: your admin controller has a role based security and you are trying to post data anonymously. sent application authentication credentials with the request

Comment: I never got this error for ajax, check url without ajax and see if you have logged in with ROLE_ADMIN or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way, send it via the symfony routing:

```
url: "{{ path('save_sort_order') }}",
```

this should be all you need

Comment: you helped me on the right way, in my case '/savesortorder' was the solution. The above url didn't work because i have the java code in an external script. Thank you!